# Reading and Writing UTC to TIMESTAMP in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I have a Java application that inserts data into a database using prepared statements. In the preparedStamement date is set in UTC format.

```
preparedStatement.setDate(index, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()), UTC);
```

I want to be sure that when read and write operations execute on the table, the response should **ALWAYS** be in UTC format. At the below query, when the data is read it will be converted to the client's timezone. I don't want TIME_COLUMN to be converted to any time zone. It should remain in the UTC time zone. How can I define TIME_COLUMN in that way?

Notes: I cannot edit the DB timezone. I cannot edit select queries using At time zone.

```
"TIME_COLUMN" TIMESTAMPTZ default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also `java.sql.Date` in its day was for an SQL `date`, never for an SQL `timestamptz`. I am sorry, I would not expect it to work what you are trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the timezone of your RDBMS to UTC, see https://medium.com/building-the-system/how-to-store-dates-and-times-in-postgresql-269bda8d6403

When that's done, whatever dates you store, they will be in UTC. Converting from UTC into something else can be done either in queries, like

```
select created_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'america/los_angeles'
from users;
```

Taken from https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-convert-utc-to-local-time-zone-in-postgresql

Or, you can convert the timezone at application level.

Comment: Hello Lajos, thanks for the comment. I edited the question added Notes section. I cannot set db's time zone and cannot change the select queries because they are written in application level and should not be changed.

Comment: @yed2393 If you are not allowed to change the database timezone, nor the queries, then I do not really see a way to cope with this situation. You will definitely need to be able to handle the timezone either at the RDBMS level or application level.